# Unable to plot more than 1k points ( Approx ) in mplleaflet in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Are there any limitations to the number of points to be plotted on maps using latitude and longitude in mplleaflet in Python ?

Whenever I plot about 1k points, it goes fine. But, as I exceed them to 8-9k ( desired number of points ), I get a full white output ( neither do I see the map )

Note: The input data is clean even after the 1000th index because, if I plot the next 1k points ranging index from 1000 to 2000 it again works well. But, if I include 2k points ( 0 : 2000 ) I get a blank space here

Following is the code I am using.

Lats_longs is a dataframe I am using which has Latitude and Longitudes data.

```
import mplleaflet as mpl

fig1, axes = plt.subplots(figsize = (11,5))
axes.scatter(Lats_Longs['LON'][0:],Lats_Longs['LAT'][0:] , s=10, alpha=0.7)

#The following 2 commented lines works fine individually.( But not both as the total points then goes to 2k )
#axes.scatter(Lats_Longs['LON'][0:1000],Lats_Longs['LAT'][0:1000] , s=10, alpha=0.7)
#axes.scatter(Lats_Longs['LON'][1000:2000],Lats_Longs['LAT'][1000:2000] , s=10, alpha=0.7)

mplleaflet.display(fig = fig1)
```

I am adding an example with simple random numbers

```
import mplleaflet as mpl
import numpy as np 

abc = np.random.uniform(low=70, high=98, size=(5000))
de = np.random.uniform(low=6, high=36, size=(5000))

fig1, axes = plt.subplots(figsize = (11,5))
axes.scatter(abc[0:1000],de[0:1000], s=10, alpha=0.7)

mplleaflet.display(fig = fig1)
```

Shows Output as :
[image]

```
import mplleaflet as mpl
import numpy as np 

abc = np.random.uniform(low=70, high=98, size=(5000))
de = np.random.uniform(low=6, high=36, size=(5000))

fig1, axes = plt.subplots(figsize = (11,5))
axes.scatter(abc[0:2000],de[0:2000], s=10, alpha=0.7)

mplleaflet.display(fig = fig1)
```

Shows output as : ( Notice the increased no. of points for plotting )

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a smaller size and smaller alpha. E.g. `scatter(...,  s=1, alpha=0.1)` ? Normally you should be able to draw millions of dots.  The idea that drawing 2000 dots would look very different from drawing 2 times 1000 dots doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes... I tried using smaller size and smaller alpha as well. I don't want to draw 2000 points separately, I am just assuring you that there is nothing wrong with the input data because separately they get plotted as expected.

Comment: Could you post both a good and a bad image? Could you create a standalone example with some random points? 10000 dots of size 20 easily can fill up the complete image. By the way, the default dot color would be blue, not white.

Comment: @JohanC Hey check out I've added an example including the output (photos) in the question.

Comment: You should use `mplleaflet.show()` if you're not running inside a notebook. Did you add `%matplotlib inline` to run it inside a notebook? You might want to open an issue at [mplleaflet's github](https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet), referring to this stackoverflow question. It might be a memory problem related to the jupyter notebook.